# "set_metadata_recursive: some changes failed" while updating Gapps-Kk-20140606-Signed.zip

Tags: google-apps, cyanogenmod, motorola-droid-4

Tonight I updated my Motorola Droid 4 from CM11-M2 to M7, and I thought I could update gapps too, but I'm getting this error:

```
set_metadata_recursive: some changes failed
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this happens because my recovery (Safestrap 3.65) doesn't support "set_metadata". So, I tried [Mentor's Gapps: no set_metadata core Gapps working with ART](http://www.internauta37.altervista.org/mentors-gapps-only-core-gapps-facebook-sync-and-working-art) (`"they are compatible with recoveries not supporting set_metadata"`) and they were flashed correctly. Based on [this XDA post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2691957),

> In these gapps there are only the AOSP Quick Search Box and Play Store
> from wich you can install every other gapp and app.
>
> In these gapps there are:
>
> - minimum core gapps
> - lib to solve the swype problem of the AOSP keyboard
> - Quick Search Box
> - Play Store
>
> These gapps are working with ART and they are compatible with recoveries not supporting set_metadata.